# Login failed for user domain\user

Tags: c#, sql, sqlconnection

I just started with writing SQL in visual studio and combining it with C#.
I made a localdatabase in my visual studio, but somehow I cant connect to it. It tells me login failed for user `domain\user`

I am using this code: `using (SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source = (LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=Employee;Integrated Security=SSPI;User ID=domain\\user;Password=mypassword"))`

Am I missing something?

When I open the Server Explorer in Visual Studio I can see `Azure`, `Data Connections` and `Servers` with my local PC in it.

Any help is much appreciated!
Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't need to provide a username and password when using SSPI

Comment: You are using Integrated Security so you don't need a UserID or Password.  SSPI uses your windows login.  You can verify that the databas is working correctly by using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) which comes with SQL Server.  The login window to SSMS should be the same as your c# application.  The error messages are better in SSMS and should indicate if there is an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `Integrated Security=SSPI;` from your connection string. If you want to log in with username/password you should not specify that you want to use integrated security at the same time.

Alternatively remove the username and password and use integrated security.

Also make sure that the user is actually created in the database, and that it has the right permissions.

Comment: I tried this, but it still gives the exact same error

Comment: And my user is just my local account of my windows

Comment: And you have created the user in the database?

Comment: I fixed it, I had to take the connection string from the SQL server object explorer and past it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your connection string is wrong according to what you want to accomplish. Yo are trying to use integrated security but specifying the user. Just remove the user and password.

Try this: "Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=Employee;Integrated Security=SSPI;"

Comment: are you sure that the local user is created on the database?

Comment: I try to login with my own username, which is part of a domain at work

Comment: and what is the result?

Comment: I fixed it, I had to take the connection string from the SQL server object explorer and past it.

Comment: glad you can do it